# How to create FactoryGirl for embedded data in test on mongoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rspec, factory-bot

I have a team model file as:

```
class Team
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :short_name, type: String
  field :sdi_team_id, type: Integer
  embeds_many :history, :class_name => "History"
end

class History
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :short_name, type: String
  field :sdi_team_id, type: Integer
  embedded_in :teams, :class_name => "Team"
end
```

For this i have to write test for creating factorygirl for team and history in a single spec file as team_spec.rb

In that file I wrote:

```
team = FactoryGirl.create(:team, sdi_team_id:team_d['sdi_team_id'])
```

It create team but I tried same for history it does not...

In my factories.rb I wrote it as:

```
factory :team do
  history { FactoryGirl.build(:history)}
end 

factory :history do

end
```

I want to create history on same spec file can any one help. am new to rails. 
I am using mongodb as my back-end. Where I am getting data from XML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got,

it just do simple just to modify my factories.rb file as

```
factory :team do
  # team data
  factory :history do
    #history data
  end

end
```